# Room migration - Is it safe to use Cursor in migration code (to get row ID)?

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration, android-cursor

This is my migration change:
[image]

Basically rename and then update some values ***based on the row id*** where `isNext = 1`.

---

I suppose I need to use a `Cursor` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55521889/1972372). So my code with auto-migration would look like this:

```
// For Auto-Migration
@RenameColumn(tableName = "Notifications", fromColumnName = "isNext", toColumnName = "wasShown")
static class MyAutoMigration implements AutoMigrationSpec {
    @Override
    public void onPostMigrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Invoked once auto migration is done
        Cursor cursor = database.query("SELECT * from Notifications WHERE wasShown = 1");
        String row_id = String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition());
        database.execSQL("UPDATE Notifications SET wasShown = 1 WHERE id < ?", new String[]{row_id});
        database.execSQL("UPDATE Notifications SET wasShown = 0 WHERE id = ?", new String[]{row_id});
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

---

**Is it in some way "risky" to use such logic in migration code?**
For example because it might throw exceptions, or something else happens that would crash the app.

I never worked with direct SQL manipulation through old-school cursors before, so I have the impression this logic might be fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issues. However, there is no need as the UPDATEs could be done without the need for a Cursor as the UPDATE could determine the value.

e.g. the SQL could be:-

```
WITH isNext(id) AS (SELECT id FROM Notifications WHERE wasShown = 1 LIMIT 1)
UPDATE Notifications SET wasShown = CASE WHEN id < (SELECT id FROM isNext) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

- **isNext** is a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) and is like a temporary table, the name could be whatever you wish, isNext was used as it was the historical name of the column.
- note that the above, even over two lines, is a single query.

The following demonstrates the above :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Notifications;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notifications (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, wasShown INTEGER);
INSERT INTO Notifications (wasShown) VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(1),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0);
/* Show the pre-update data */
SELECT * FROM Notifications;

/* Data prepared so the actual UPDATE */
WITH isNext(id) AS (SELECT id FROM Notifications WHERE wasShown = 1 LIMIT 1)
UPDATE Notifications SET wasShown = CASE WHEN id < (SELECT id FROM isNext) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

/* Show the post-update data */
SELECT * FROM Notifications;
/* cleanup demo */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Notifications;
```

The pre-update query results in :-

[image]

The post-date query results in :-

[image]

[Here's an SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/15190)

You code could then be :-

```
// For Auto-Migration
@RenameColumn(tableName = "Notifications", fromColumnName = "isNext", toColumnName = "wasShown")
static class MyAutoMigration implements AutoMigrationSpec {
    @Override
    public void onPostMigrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Invoked once auto migration is done
        database.execSQL("WITH isNext(id) AS (SELECT id FROM Notifications WHERE wasShown = 1 LIMIT 1) UPDATE Notifications SET wasShown = CASE WHEN id < (SELECT id FROM isNext) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;");

    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, thank you for so much detail in your answer! I have to admit that SQL statement looks a little bit intimidating to an SQL noob like me, but it's probably the safer and more efficient way than the cursor.

Comment: I forgot one use-case: when there is no `isNext=1` value and all entries are 0, I would have to set them all to `wasShown=1`. I've been trying to do this with your query and `CASE WHEN EXISTS` but with no result. Could you possibly offer a suggestion?

Comment: Ahhh, I made it work! See my answer below. Hopefully it's not too inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I had to adapt MikeT's great answer to fit one more use-case in my migration:
When there was no value with `isNext=1` left in the old table, all values in the new table had to be set to `wasShown=1`.

After some trial and error I made the following conditional logic work to cover all of my cases:

```
WITH isNext(id) AS (SELECT id FROM Notifications WHERE wasShown = 1 LIMIT 1)
UPDATE Notifications SET wasShown = 
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT id FROM Notifications WHERE wasShown = 1 LIMIT 1)
THEN CASE WHEN id < (SELECT id FROM isNext) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
ELSE 1 END;
```